# Spring listener concurrentConsumers for an MQ queue

Tags: spring, concurrency, jms

I am new to Spring listener JMS events from MQ.

Will there be problems in application performance if JMS concurrentConsumers value is used as the default value which is "1"

What factors to consider in finding the ideal value for the concurrentConsumers for an application

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, setting the value to 1 means you only have one consumer. In other words, it is not multi-threaded in terms of processing the messages arriving at the queue.

What value to set depends on your requirements. You can do a performance test to see the difference.

BTW, I'm new to Spring JMS too. Just built a JMS application in Spring.